# Oracle Stored Procedure and custom data type

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I have an Oracle stored procedure which takes two parameters: a custom data type and a string.

Calling the stored procedure in Oracle, I would do the following:

```
EXECUTE MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(MYTYPE_T(99, 231), 'mystring')
```

How can I execute this using C#? I understand that I need to setup the command to be a stored procedure, but how do I specify the first parameter as custom data type?

### Update:

`MYTYPE_T` is `TABLE OF NUMBER` created via

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE mytype_t AS TABLE OF NUMBER ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do this easily with the [deprecated System.Data.OracleClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/system-data-oracleclient-update)
but you can utilize [oracle's ODP](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html) with using UDTs.  If that is not an option, I am unsure how you can do it via parameters in C# with System.Data.

ODP does come with a lot of examples and there are examples in the above links.

I am going to add some more links that will hopefully help:

1. [visual studio ODP index](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/developer-tools/visual-studio/)
2. [this shows you exactly how to
   utilize the ODT to create you custom
   class wrappers and call them](https://web.archive.org/web/20110319183703/http://st-curriculum.oracle.com:80/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/udt/udt_otn.htm#t8) (do
   note that this is midway through,
   they walk through using the tool to
   create the custom types above it in
   the example -- this walkthrough is
   quite thorough and should get you
   directly where you need to be)
3. [Download](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html): now this guy also
   installs sample files, this is
   another terrific example of exactly
   what you need to do: once installed
   goto [directory path you
   install]..\product\11.2.0\client_1\odp.net\samples\4\UDT\object1.cs

It really pays to allow the ODT tools for Visual studio to create your classes for your UDTs for you (e.g. IOracleCustomType and such) .  you can then go into them and amend them to suit your needs. then once all is said and done (snippet from object1.cs):

```
    Person p1   = new Person();
p1.Name     = "John";
p1.Address  = "Address1";
p1.Age = 20;

// Establish a connection to Oracle
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();

// Update Person object and insert it into a database table
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql1, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter();

param1.OracleDbType   = OracleDbType.Object;
param1.Direction      = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

// Note: The UdtTypeName is case-senstive
param1.UdtTypeName     = "SCOTT.ODP_OBJ1_SAMPLE_PERSON_TYPE";   
param1.Value           = p1;

cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

also note that Person class must implement **IOracleCustomType** (which can be created by following the link in #2)

```
/* Person Class
   An instance of a Person class represents an ODP_OBJ1_SAMPLE_PERSON_TYPE object
   A custom type must implement INullable and IOracleCustomType interfaces
*/
public class Person : INullable, IOracleCustomType
```

The above is for a full custom type, but you are after an associative array ODP binding:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/05/14/odp-net-associative-arrays.aspx

you'll want to use

```
param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
```

and everything should fall into place

Comment: Updated my question. A sample of ODP would be great. I can't seem to find the specific scenario I need in the ODP sample files.

Comment: What value should `sql1` have? I is it just the name of the stored procedure? I have updated my question with the exact type I need to pass to the stored procedure.

Comment: @Baddie, I believe you will want to use an associativearray, I put in a nice link above

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom datatype from C# to Oracle procedure only if this datatype is DB-defined. Have a look [at this article](http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-pass-arrays-from-net-c-to-oracle.html), this should help you get started.