# Read Table out Parameter from Oracle procedure without Sys_refcursor in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, procedure

I have one package there i created one procedure like

```
PROCEDURE   GET_Custome_Data(my_tab_var OUT Data_Tab);
```

in package i create variable of type record in which i have different type of variable like

```
Type Rec_Tab Is Record
    (
    customer_id   VARCHAR2(40),
    product_id    VARCHAR2(40),
    history       Varchar2(1)   
    );
```

after that i create a table of type Rec_Tab.
like

```
type Data_Tab is table of Rec_Tab INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

in that table i added records in that table.

now data is in my_tab_var which is out parameter of procedure. i want to read that parameter in c# without using Sys_refcursor.

thanks of help in advance......

Comment: You can run a query from C# as `select * from TABLE(GET_Custome_Data)`. However, in this case you would have to use a FUNCTION instead of a procedure with OUT parameter.

Comment: yes this will only work with function but we have procedure...we searching solution for procedure.

Comment: Having a procedure with only 1 out parameter would be rather predestinated for function. Anyway, check [Oracle User-Defined Types (UDTs) and .NET Custom Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featUDTs.htm#ODPNT378) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098944/oracle-stored-procedure-and-custom-data-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980421/c-pass-a-user-defined-type-to-a-oracle-stored-procedure